# Django application Logs not showing in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, logging

I have a Django application deployed on Heroku.
I am using the default logging module, and my logs show normally in development, both when `DEBUG` is True and False.

Though, I am unable to see the logs when deployed to heroku with the command `heroku logs --tail`.

Here is the content of my `settings.py` file:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} [{asctime}] module:{module} - {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'stream': sys.stdout,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {  # I tried replacing this with 'root'
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

In my files such as `views.py`:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.debug('something...')
```

And finally, in my `Procfile`:

```
release: python manage.py migrate --settings=myapp.deploy_settings
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file -
```

I also tried with `web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file=-` as mentioned in a StackOverflow post, without success.

What is causing this?

Comment: Please try this if you haven't already. 
`django_heroku.settings(locals(), logging=False)`
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54445376/4669744

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `logging=False` to `django_heroku.settings(locals(), logging=False)` solved the issue.